# find , replace and add a new pattern

Tags: awk

I have below kind of entries in a file.  While I can easily replace  `RAW` to `VARCHAR` as,

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1};{gsub(/RAW/,"VARCHAR")}; 1'
```

I am trying to find a way to add a pattern after replacement

For example here is my data

```
COL1    RAW(64)       NOT NULL,    
COL2    RAW(255)      NOT NULL,
```

here is desired data

```
COL1    VARCHAR (64)  FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL,    
COL2    VARCHAR (255) FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL,
```

i.e `RAW` should be replaced with `VARCHAR` - this part I am able to do using `awk`, However I am not sure how to add `FOR BIT DATA`

Comment: How did you fail? What is your attempt?

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1};{gsub(/RAW/,"VARCHAR")}; 1'  i could replace RAW but no idea about how to add new pattern after replacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `GNU Awk` you can use its `gensub()` function to define a `regex` match strictly for containing those two patterns

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/(.*)\<RAW\>\(([0-9]+)\)(.*)\<NOT NULL\>/, "\\1VARCHAR (\\2)\tFOR BIT DATA NOT NULL", "g", $0)}1' file
```

For an input file,

```
cat file
COL1    RAW(64)       NOT NULL,
COL2    RAW(255)      NOT NULL,
COL3    NOTRAW(255)      NOT NULL,
```

It returns as

```
COL1    VARCHAR (64)    FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL,
COL2    VARCHAR (255)   FOR BIT DATA NOT NULL,
COL3    NOTRAW(255)      NOT NULL,
```

The above needs the pattern `RAW` and `NOT NULL` both to present for replacement

---

If you want to match only lines having `RAW` do,

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/(.*)\<RAW\>\(([0-9]+)\)(.*)/, "\\1VARCHAR (\\2)\tFOR BIT DATA NOT NULL", "g", $0)}1' file
```